# .NET 4, how to execute dynamic vb code like windows workflow 4 does

Tags: dynamic, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

Just curious how Windows Workflow 4 executes vb code. Can I use the same techique to execute vb.net code at run-time?

Answer (score 1):

It's atually pretty specialized - before execution it compiles the VB code to an expression tree of activities in System.Activities.Expressions. I wouldn't recommend it as a way of executing general VB.net code.

You might find stuff about hosting DLR scripting languages such as IronPython interesting... I don't know if there's a similar hostable VB compiler available.

Comment: yeah the dynamic VB execution is based on the DLR and the vb scripting engine is internal so no way to reuse that. I went the IronPython way. thanks